# .htaccess rewrite "?p=" to "/"

Tags: regex, .htaccess

For example:

`http://domain.com/comments?p=73819`

becomes

`http://domain.com/comments/73819`.

How can I do this in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /comments\?p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /comments/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^comments/([0-9]+)$ /comments?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That works! Just a question, this won't interfere with for example `$_GET['p']` requests will it?

Comment: @frosty the first rule redirects requests with the query string to the one without, the second rule internally rewrites the request *back* to using the query string, so the php scripts will be able to fetch the `p` GET variable again

Comment: Ah, so that way links will actually be able to fetch information since they'd lack the query string. Thanks.

Comment: it seems to be treating it like a folder because the CSS doesn't load unless I use `../`, and in addition when I attempt to echo `$_GET['p']` nothing is echoed. When I delete the rule it works fine

Comment: @frosty CSS is probably not working because you've changed the relative URI base by adding another `/` in the URL. If your css is linked using relative URLs, you need to make them all absolute